Need help adding currency conversion to this code
I found some code here: https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/woocommerce-set-minimum-cart-amount-user-role/
that prevents wholesale customers from putting in an order unless they satisfy a minimum cart amount.  The problem is that if I change my site's currency from USD to CAD, for example, the threshold in CAD is lower than the USD equivalent because $250 CAD is only ~$183 USD.  The opposite would be true for EUR.  $250 USD would be ~267 EUR.
This is the cart page code for cart-totals.php file:
   <div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout"> <?php
   //Get current user and check the user role.

   $current_screen_user = wp_get_current_user();

// In my scenario “wholesale_buyer” is the user role for which I want this validation. You can add your user roles.

    if( in_array( 'wholesale_buyer', $current_screen_user->roles ) ) {

      $minimum = 50; // Set the minimum amt.
      $cart_amt = WC()->cart->subtotal; // cart sub_total, this is actual total excluding discounts and shipping.

                if ( $cart_amt < $minimum ) {
          if( is_cart() ) {
        //Added notices for cart page.
              wc_print_notice(
                  sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' ,
                      wc_price( $minimum ),
                      wc_price( $cart_amt )
                  ), 'error'
              );
          } else {
        //Added notice msg for checkout page.

              wc_add_notice(
                  sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' ,
                      wc_price( $minimum ),
                      wc_price( $cart_amt)
                  ), 'error'
              );
          }
      } else {
          do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' );
      }
    } else {
      do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' );
    }
    ?>
   </div>

This is the checkout page code that goes into function.php or in my case gets added to my snippets plugin:
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wdm_wu_minimum_order_amount' );

function wdm_wu_minimum_order_amount() {

    $current_screen_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( in_array( 'wholesale_buyer', $current_screen_user->roles ) ) {

      $minimum = 50;

    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum ) {
       if( is_cart() ) {
           wc_print_notice(
               sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' ,

                   wc_price( $minimum ),
                   wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
               ), 'error'
           );

       } else {
           wc_add_notice(
               sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' ,

                   wc_price( $minimum ),
                   wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )

               ), 'error'
           );
       } } } }


In order to fix the issue of differing currency values, we need to dynamically calculate the minimum amount based on the current currency exchange rate. Here’s how we can modify our code to done this.

We need to fetch the current exchange rate by using an API to get the latest exchange rates.
Also need to use the fetched exchange rate to convert the minimum amount.

